# How can I remove nvidia drivers with its patches in my kernel?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, kernel

I've removed all nvidia drivers with apt: **apt list --installed | grep nvidia** returns nothing. But if I take a look at dmesg, I see for example:

```
[    4.148454] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 410.104, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 430.50.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
```

and also if I run **lsmod | grep nvidia**:

```
nvidia_drm             49152  1
nvidia_modeset       1114112  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              19038208  1 nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        180224  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   483328  4 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
ipmi_msghandler       102400  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
```

how do I remove all this stuff from my system?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally managed to do it and it was not that complex. First, I had to get name of my current kernel:

```
stiv@gaidar:~$ uname -a
Linux gaidar 5.0.0-31-generic #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 10:20:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

then I went to this folder:

```
stiv@gaidar:/lib/modules$ ls /lib/modules/
5.0.0-23-generic  5.0.0-25-generic  5.0.0-27-generic  5.0.0-29-generic  5.0.0-31-generic
```

It contained **.ko** files inside:

```
stiv@gaidar:~$ ls /lib/modules/5.0.0-31-generic/updates/dkms
nvidia-drm.ko  nvidia.ko  nvidia-modeset.ko  nvidia-uvm.ko
```

I deleted them and thus get rid of this brilliant driver.